# I add my model association belongs_to but no column added to the suitable table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models named class1 and student,after I create them,I added association.
Then my models are:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :birthdate, :name
  belongs_to :class1
end

class Class1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :students
end
```

I tried to create instance for the models by rails console:

```
2.0.0-p0 :001 > c=Class1.new(:name=>"A")
 => #<Class1 id: nil, name: "A", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0-p0 :002 > c.save
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `class1s` (`created_at`, `name`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2013-03-12 08:40:03', 'A', '2013-03-12 08:40:03')
   (40.7ms)  COMMIT
 => true
```

But when I tried add student for the class I got an error:

```
2.0.0-p0 :003 > s=c.students.build:name=>"Moshe"
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: class1_id
```

The column class_id really don’t exist in the database-why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's your responsibility to add appropriated migration for that association.

In console:

```
rails g migration add_class1_references_to_students class1:references
```

And then:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: make sure that you don't forget to add indexes.

Comment: Migration generator always add indicies, when `references` used.

Comment: I'm not sure though in which rails version `class1:references` appears.. May be only in 4.beta. Anyway you need migration to add `class1_id` column and index for that.

Comment: you're right. i misread something in the guide about using the references helper which is talking about foreign key constraints. must have confused it with that.

Comment: I tried it but I got an error: rake db:migrate
==  AddClass1ReferencesToStudents: migrating ==================================
-- add_column(:students, :class1, :references)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'references' at line 1: ALTER TABLE `students` ADD `class1` references thank you for the help!